# Plotting "on the fly" possible?

Tags: plotting, resource-management

`ListPlot` needs a list (duh). Assume that you have a problem where time is not the issue, but space, e.g. compute and plot the first billion values of Fibonacci[n]/GoldenRatio^n. Iteratively you can do it in O(1) time for each step (if you cheat with GoldenRatio - it's just an example). Storing all these values in a list to plot it...just no.

Thus, can you do something like `ListPlot` with the list being generated on the fly, the plot function just looking at the element currently generated? (Related note, wrong SE: can Python's matlibplot do it? You could put that into comments if you happen to know.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution uses the "RingBuffer" data structure.

```
Dynamic[ds];
npts = 16;
xticks = Transpose[{Range[1, npts], ToString /@ Range[-npts, -1]}];
```

Initialize:

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["RingBuffer", npts];
Do[ds["PushBack", i], {i, npts}];
ds["Elements"]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}

ListPlot updates with a `Refresh` interval of 0.5s:

```
Dynamic[
 Refresh[
  ListLinePlot[First@Normal[ds]
   , PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}
   , Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}
   ], UpdateInterval -> 0.5]
 ]
```

Test: (add 10 values)

```
Do[
 ds["PushBack", RandomInteger[{1, 7}]];
 Pause[0.5],
 {i, 1, 10}
 ]
```

Result: (starts with the values from 1-16 initially and then the recently entered points are kept only.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it. +1

Comment: I upped this one as it is immediately clear to me what a ring buffer does. Since both offers use "Dynamic", I give that function a closer look :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using "Dynamic". We simulate the long calculation by "Pause":

```
x = 1;
tot = Graphics[Point[{x, x^2}]];
next[t_] := (tot = 
     Show[tot, Graphics[Point[{++x, x^2}]], Axes -> True, 
      AspectRatio -> 1];);
Dynamic[tot]
Do[next[tot]; Pause[0.5];, {20}]
```

[image]